# get json array back through javascript in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an external file in php, outputed as json format

I want the data to be send back to jquery in arrays .... how to do it ?

**php:**

```
$options = "<option value="data0">data 0<option>
<option value="data1">data 1<option>
<option value="data2">data 2<option>
<option value="data3">data 3<option>
<option value="data4">data 4<option>";

$arr = array("options" => $options);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**jquery json:**

```
var new_data = ' data.options ';

$(div_list).html(new_data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("/resource/",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.options, function(i,item){
          $('#select').append( $(item) );
          });
        });
  });

</script>
```

Though I really can't tell without looking at the exact JSON output.